# Encouraging code sharing

Tags: discussion

Sometime you come across someone who has been trying to figure out a problem and search throughout the Joomla Docs but not found anything. They sometimes end up figuring out the problem for themselves. Also with the flexible nature of Joomla, new things are found out which one might have never thought was possible Do we encourage people to share their code which could then possible help update the Joomla Docs in the future? If this is encourage and allowed, then what would we prevent it from getting a site full of code snippets that may or may not work?

Thoughts and opinions would be great

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't encourage it to much.

You could run into copyright issues when you take a code example from any Stack Exchange sites as they are licensed as CC.

Comment: I'd suggest linking to a code snippet at a third party source with the copyright and license displayed to get around that.

Comment: Can we negotiate with SE to have a condition that snippets can be used under any OSI approved license?

Comment: I agree that it would be a great if that point is negotiable as the whole ethos of Joomla is based on freedom!